# Python Networked Chat

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I was working on a networked chat by following a tutorial. I have two modules, chatServer.py3 and chatClient.py3. On starting the server and then a client and attempting to send a message I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "chatClient.py3", line 49, 
in <module> 
Main() File "chatClient.py3", line 38, in Main 
s.sendto(alias+": "+message, server) 
socket.error: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

Please keep in mind that I am a rookie and therefore I would appreciate if the solutions along with their explanations were simplistic.

### chatClient.py3

```
import socket, time, threading
tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def recieveing(name,sock):
    locked = False
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.aquire()
                  locked = True
        while True:
            data , addr = sock.recv(1024)
            print str(data)
        except:
            pass
        finally:        
            if locked:  
                tLock.release()


def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 0
    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.setblocking(0)

    rT = threading.Thread(target=recieveing,args=("RecivedThread",s))
    rT.start()

    alias = raw_input("Name: ")
    message = raw_input(alias+"-> ")

    while message != "q":
        if message != "":
            s.sendto(alias+": "+message, server)
        tLock.aquire()
        message = raw_input(alias+"-> ")
       tLock.release()
        time.sleep(0.2)

    shutdown = True
    rT.join()
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

### chatServer.py3

```
import socket,time

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
clients = []


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

quitting = False
print "Server Started."

while not quitting:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if "Quit" in str(data):
            quitting = True
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
        print time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + " : : "+str(data)

        for client in clients:
            s.sendto(data, client)
        except:
            pass


s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind your client to the host and port. The bind command defines where the server needs to listen. The client needs to connect to the server. Like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

s.connect(server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, so it would be correct for me to replace "s.bind()" in the chatClient.py3 module with "s.connect(server)" ?