# networked chats in python using UDP

Tags: python, server, client

`Chat_UDP server started
socket binded to 6000
The addr from client is: ('127.0.0.1', 57344)
The addr from client is: ('127.0.0.1', 57344)`

link--> [Python Networked Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820667/python-networked-chat)

tha same question in python 3
for me i am unable to print the client access the server
and uanble to see client 1 msg in client screen and vice versa
plz help

Comment: see the server o/p no time the client connect is shown my code is same as that in tat link

Comment: Post your code here and define error exactly!

Comment: @arman the code is same as in that link everything same when i sent message from client 1 it is not reflected in server and hence in client 2 so on